# iOS Printer Simulator Errors - Air Print

Tags: ios, xcode, printing, simulator

There's something wrong with my Printer Simulator. Trying to print while running https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/samplecode/Recipes_+_Printing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011098-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2 will cause the following errors to appear in the Xcode console:

`2014-03-26 17:23:47.563 Recipes[3455:3c07] Simulated\032Label\032Printer\032@\032[redacted]Mac\032mini._ipps._tcp.local.: 
Unable to connect to [redacted]-mac-mini.local.:8632: Bad file descriptor
2014-03-26 17:23:47.570 Recipes[3455:3c07] Simulated\032Label\032Printer\032@\032[redacted]Mac\032mini._ipps._tcp.local.: 
Connection is untrusted: Unable to establish a secure connection to host.`

Here is what I have tried without success:

- Reinstalling Xcode
- debugging Bonjour connections
- created a new user on the mac mini

What else could I try? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am getting the same error and the answer below did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Nope, I tried on a different machine and it worked. But on the machine with the original problem, I had to install handyPrint, which helps with printing to a PDF.

Comment: Awesome suggestion/find. Thanks, Victor!

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `/private/var/tmp/printd` fixed it for me. I found that answer in [AirPrint Connection Refused Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163092/airprint-connection-refused-error).

Comment: Couldnt find that file.. I am in Mac High Sierra. Hardware tools 10.1

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone. If your printer simulator stops working, see my answer over here: [AirPrint Connection Refused Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163092/airprint-connection-refused-error) -- short version, make sure you only have 1 active network connection to your network at once (popping out the ethernet worked for me)