# AirPrint Simulator - Unable to find server credentials

Tags: ios, printing

I'm unable to print to my printer simulator...

Here's what I've done:

- Found Printer Simulator

  - https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode
  - download and install  Additional Tools for Xcode (Latest non-beta version)
  - Open the resulting Hardware folder and then the Printer Simulator
- Try printing to one of the printer simulators while watching the printer log (I used my mac)

  - I got an error when trying to print.

    - [05/Feb/2018:09:24:38 -0600] [Client 1] Unable to encrypt connection from 192.168.10.108: Unable to find server credentials.

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163092/airprint-connection-refused-error/11805489#11805489) but no luck.

- Tried removing `/private/var/tmp/printd`

  - I didn't have `printd` in the directory
- Ensured I only have one network connection (wireless)

Comment: Did you solved this? I am having exactly the same problem :(

Comment: If you just need it to work, turn Wi-Fi off on your Mac. As per afnan's deleted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found at least a workaround:

Because the log of the print simulator says, there was a problem with something about encryption, I looked out for a print option without encryption. And there is!

When you add the printer, you can select which type of communication protocol or whatever you'd like to take. Default is "Secure AirPrint". However, you can select "AirPrint" (You can even select special drivers. Probably, you won't have any problems with the right ones, but I didn't try). And that works!

There's one bad thing: I got on this problem while testing printing from the iOS Simulator. There, you can't (or it seems like you can't) choose between "Secure AirPrint" and "AirPrint". So I'm still looking for the final solution....

Comment: It very seems like the printer simulator has some problems: I connected a real printer via "Secure AirPrint" and the iOS simulator and my iOS App could print to this printer. So I think, there are some problems with the printer simulator.

Comment: same problem here. Cannot print to simulator.

Comment: Sure wish we could use this from a simulator